# ChoiceBoxes Selection

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

So, I'm kind of bit new to Javafx.. My Question is as follows -
I am creating an application and i'm using Gridpane as a layout, Now inside gridpane I have no of labels, textfileds, buttons and datepicker ..
I am also using choiceboxes.. So what i want is when i select particular value from a choicebox.. I want my other labels or textfield inside gridpane to shift downwards and in that place i want new labels and textfields to appear..
How to do that, any example would be great.. in other words point me to the action event what i could use..

Note: Do I have to create 2 separate scenes and call the scene#2 when a particular value is selected from choice box.. but that would mean I will be duplicating the full scene for just adding two more labels and textboxes...

Thanks

Comment: Property that can be listened to for changes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ChoiceBox.html#valueProperty

Comment: I think you misunderstood me I guess... I do not want to add values ..I wan to introduce new textfield and labels inside a scene...

Comment: If your right than can you demonstrate an example plz.. Add a choicebox and below it a label and a textfield in a scene and then on selecting a value say for instance "Yes"  display a label and textbox underneath the choicebox; moving the 1st label and textfield on the scene; 1 row down

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use another scene. You can remove elements from your pane using method:

```
YOUR_PANE.getChilders().remove(THERE_WILL_BE_YOUR_OBJECT);
```

To catch moment then you select item from ComboBox, you have to use method:

```
COBOBOX.setOnAtion(event -> { 
//logic there.
}
```

It's all that you need. ( :

Comment: thanx for your answer but I rather shifted all my Label and TextField 1 row down using a if statement and looping all the needed nodes ... additionally, added needed nodes dynamically ..

Answer (score 0):

```
choiceBox.setOnAtion((e) -> {
```

gridPane.getChildren().add(0, your_node);

});